# Proper handling of child Greenlets

Tags: greenlets

I am creating tasks by inheriting from `Greenlet`. I have a single parent task that calls `start()` on two children in its `_run()`. Elsewhere (it happens to be a systemd service) `start()` and `join()` are called.

The behavior seems correct. For example the use of a `Queue` with timeouts achieves the desired effect but I haven't found a good way to shutdown the children from say `KeyboardInterrupt` or by registering a callback to the parent task for `SIGTERM`. In the handler I would call `child1.kill()` and 'child2.kill()`but only the first called seemed to raise`GreenletExit`.

I never call `join()` on the children and I'm not sure how I would do this properly. Am I misusing the library?

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I was handling `gevent.greenlet.GreenletExit` in the child tasks. If you need to handle the exit you can catch and reraise this exception.